# Accessing Euro Internet from USA (via Europe)

Tags: internet, ip, europe

I am doing some traveling work that requires me to have an european IP Address. This is fine when I am abroad but it is tough when I am the US or elsewhere.

My first instinct was for to buy dedicated Windows Hosting in europe and then remote desktop in. However I think that would be too slow. I would prefer just to have the network data sent rather than entire screens. My second instinct was to use a VPN, although I am not sure this would work.  I looked into it a little further and It seems most hosting packages do not allow VPNs.

Provided I find a hosting package that allows it, would a VPN work? Or is there some other better way I am not thinking of that I could VPN in, or do something else to have programs that are running on my PC originate from Europe and operating with an european IP address?

Any thoughts would be very helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

It is very unclear to me what your requirements are?

- an IP address that resolves to a european location should someone look it up.
- a computer that must reside in EU for legal reasons
- an email/web address in an EU address space

Please try to be more precise in describing what you need, what your restrictions are.

I am not at all convinced you need any of the expensive hosting/VPN stuff ... a proxy, as suggested above, might all you need!